# How to extract column index of a dataframe with the variable name?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I would like to extract the column index of a variable of a dataframe using the variable name.

here is the df for exemple:

```
>df 

  Mean  Var  Max
a  1     0.5  3
b  1.5   0.4  4
c  0.7   0.3  2.5
d  0.3   0.1  0.5
```

I want to "reverse" this:

```
> variable.names(df[2])
[1] "Var"
```

with something like that:

```
> variable.names(df$Var)
NULL
```

But getting "2"  instead of "NULL"

here is my entire problem:

```
my_fct ← function(data, v_cont, v_cat){  
  for (i in 1:nlevels(as.factor(v_cat))){      
      sub <- subset(data , v_cat == levels(as.factor(v_cat))[i])     
      sub_stat <- c(levels(as.factor(v_cat))[i],                    
                    mean( **sub[,COLINDEX(v_cat)**] , na.rm = TRUE)     
      mat_stat <- rbind(mat_stat, sub_stat)
```

**sub[,COLINDEX(v_cat)** is what need to solve. How to select the initial variable in my new matrix freshly created?

Note: v_cat and v_cont have the following form: df$variable1 , df$variable2

thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear about the situation.  But based on the function provided, it can rewritten by passing the column name and subsetting with `[[` instead of passing the `df$variable1` or `df$variable2`

```
my_fct <- function(data, v_cont, v_cat){  
  mat_stat <- NULL
  for (i in 1:nlevels(as.factor(data[[v_cat]]))){      
      sub <- subset(data , data[[v_cat]] == 
              levels(as.factor(data[[v_cat]]))[i])     
      sub_stat <- c(levels(as.factor(data[[v_cat]]))[i],                    
                    mean(sub[,v_cat] , na.rm = TRUE)  
       mat_stat <- rbind(mat_stat, sub_stat)
                    
    }
    return(mat_stat)
}
```

-testing

```
my_fct(df, "variable1", "variable2")
```

---

With the OP's original function if the input is `df$variable1`, `df$variable2`, an option is to use `deparse(subsitute` to capture the argument, extract the column name with `sub` and use that as column name

```
my_fct <- function(data, v_cont, v_cat){ 
  nm1 <- sub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(v_cat)))
  mat_stat <- NULL
  for (i in 1:nlevels(as.factor(v_cat))){      
      sub <- subset(data , v_cat == levels(as.factor(v_cat))[i])     
      sub_stat <- c(levels(as.factor(v_cat))[i],                    
                    mean(sub[, nm1] , na.rm = TRUE)     
      mat_stat <- rbind(mat_stat, sub_stat)
      }
      
      return(mat_stat)
      
}
```

-testing

```
my_fct(df, df$variable1, df$variable2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to LMc(+1) solution -> We could use `grep`:

```
df <- structure(list(Mean = c(1, 1.5, 0.7, 0.3), Var = c(0.5, 0.4, 
0.3, 0.1), Max = c(3, 4, 2.5, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"))

grep("Var", colnames(df))
```

output:

```
[1] 2
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you a lot  but actually I can't use "Var" but only df$Var. 
Any other idea to get this?

Comment: `df` should be loaded in your Environment. Then you can use the code above easily! See my update!

Comment: This is another situation. You should update your question!

Comment: @Corentvn did you meant `names(df["Var"])#
[1] "Var"`

Comment: Hello @akrun, yeah but actually I only enter df$Var in my function so i can't use names(df["var"]), If names(df$Var) was working it could be nice but it's not ^^

Comment: @Corentvn When you do `df$Var`, it is returning the values and not the data.frame.  So the `names` doesn't work there.  where as `df['Var']` returns a data.frame with a single column 'Var'

Comment: @Corentvn how do you plan to call the function `my_fct`?

Comment: Instead of `df$variable1` and `df$variable2`, you may pass `"variable1"`, `"variable2"` and then subset the data with `df[[v_cont]]` `df[[v_cat]]` In this way you can get the column names as such wihtout having to use `deparse(substitute(` etc?

Comment: Please See akrun's answer. that should now solve your problem!

Comment: Wow yeah just so simple, Sometimes it's better to get around the probleme instead of trying to solve it ^^

Thank you a lot guys !!

Comment: @TarJae its okay.  It is your answer that finds the index OP asked for

Answer (score 1):

Use `match`:

```
match("Var", colnames(df))
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you a lot  but actually I can't use "Var" but only df$Var. 
Any other idea to get this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it using `which`

```
df <- data.frame(Mean=c(1,1.5,0.7,0.3),Var=c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.1),Max=c(3,4,2.5,0.5))
df

  Mean Var Max
1  1.0 0.5 3.0
2  1.5 0.4 4.0
3  0.7 0.3 2.5
4  0.3 0.1 0.5


which(colnames(df)=="Var")
```

Output:

```
[1] 2
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you a lot  but actually I can't use "Var" but only df$Var. 
Any other idea to get this?